# Numerical Series - Cauch Criterion

Tags: calculus

There is a numerical series: 1 + 1/2 + (1/3 + 1/4) + (1/5+...+1/8)+... which I would like to prove through Cauchy criterion that is divergent. 
I reached the conclusion that the general formula of the sequence, according to which each term of the series above is constructed, is [1 + 1/(2^n)].
I would like for your guidance if my way of thinking is correct.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the sequence is. Are you calculating the harmonic series?

Comment: This proof is actually often used. It is shown that the harmionic series contains infinite many partial sums not intersecting , each at least $\frac{1}{2}$ , which immediately implies the divergence.

Comment: It is absolutely clear! Thank you very much!